# restore mock of imported class function in ts-jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

**Issue**

I am mocking a function (only one) which is imported from another class which is being called inside the main class. I am able to mock the function and return the values which I provide. But I am not able to restore the mocked function back to normal for the subsequent tests.

Any help would be appreciated!

Framework Using: jest + ts-jest

**Code**

~main.ts

```
import {SubClass} from './subclass.ts'
export class MainClass {
 let sub: SubClass = new SubClass()

public async Car(){
  let start = await sub.key();
  return start
}

}
```

~sub.ts

```
export class SubClass{ 

public async key(){
  return "you can start the car"
}
}
```

main.test.ts

```
import {SubClass} from './subclass.ts'
import {MainClass} from './mainclass.ts'
import {mocked} from 'ts-jest/utils'

jest.mock(./subclass.ts)

let main = new MainClass()
let sub = new SubClass()
let mockedFn = mocked(sub,true)

mockedFn.key = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => console.log('mocking succesfull'))

afterEach(()=>{
mockedFn.key.mockRestore() // tried mockClear(), mockReset()
}

it('test for main func mocked result',async ()=>{
 const result = await main.car()
 expect(result).toEqual("mocking succesfull")

}
it('test for main func result',async ()=>{
 const result = await main.car()
 expect(result).toEqual("you can start the car") // getting result as undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original `mockedFn.key` method is lost when it's reassigned, there's no way how Jest could restore it:

```
mockedFn.key = jest.fn()
```

It should be:

```
jest.spyOn(mockedFn, 'key').mockImplementation(...)
```

If a method or property is supposed to be restored, it should never be spied/mocked by assigning `jest.fn()` directly. This especially applies to mocked globals that can cross-contaminate tests.

Comment: I tried this method and it's also not restoring the mock and not even mocking the implementation. It's returning 'undefined'

Comment: Then the problem with `jest.spyOn` is that `sub` instance that is mocked that isn't in use anywhere; main.ts creates its own instance. I have not much experience with ts-jest but this doesn't seem it can help here. Mock the method on class proto with regular Jest, `jest.spyOn(SubClass.prototype, 'key').mockResolvedValue('foo')`. As for restoring, do all spy work in beforeEach/it, use jest.restoreAllMocks() or better Jest config restore option. This restores all Jest spies and doesn't cross-contaminate tests.